# MacBook Pro not booting after small update (patch) Big Sur

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

I have a Macbook Pro Retina, 15", mid-2015 which was upgraded to Big Sur successfully. Some days later I got the notification of a "small security upgrade" which I applied and my Mac did not restart. Now I am working in safe mode. I have tried Disk Utility and it says all is ok. I have also tried in verbose mode, however I can not see any errors and the Mac does not startup. I have also removed all startup items.

Comment: Can you boot to (internal) Recovery? If so, you can safely overlay the OS from there, without losing data.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i booted with command + r (is this the (internal) Recovery?) selected install Mac big sur and it worked fine.

Comment: That's the one. Glad it worked for you :)